# Converting NetCDF to Raster in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, netcdf

I recently checked the climate data from IPCC. The data format is .nc. I cannot directly use file in the ArcGIS to do the calculation.

Anyone met this issue before?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.

Answer (score 1):

You could try going through the steps in this Tutorial:  http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/netcdf/exercise-1-displaying-a-raster-layer-from-a-netcdf-file.htm

The instructions may vary slightly since you have 10.2 and the instructions are for 10.3. Try these steps and let us know what you've tried/where you get stuck.

According to the Tutorial, you can use the tool [Make NetCDF Raster Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/multidimension-toolbox/make-netcdf-raster-layer.htm).

Comment: Great! Quick reminder since you're new to GIS Stackexchange: Please remember to mark this as accepted if it is the answer that works best for you.